# Highlight defined python module/class names in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I'd like to have all the module/class names defined in my python code to get highlighted. For example, when I have defined a module "foo" and I call a function "bar" from it using "foo.bar()" then I'd like to have foo get highlighted. Similarly I'd like this feature for calling static methods from a class.

The python mode that comes with emacs (GNU emacs 24.3.1) doesn't do this. I've also tried the emacs highlight-defined mode but looks like it only works for lisp language.

I'd appreciate any comment on how to get this work in emacs.